# appending text in a span tag using javascript

Tags: javascript

Trying to write test from javascript in a span

```
<span>
    <script  type="text/javascript">document.write("thisStringIsGood".replace(/([A-Z])/g, ' $1').replace(/^./, function(str){ return str.toUpperCase(); }));</script>
</span>
```

but firebug show's an error `InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable`

-----updated question-------

```
<xsl:for-each select="ColumnName">
    <script  type="text/javascript">document.write("thisStringIsGood".replace(/([A-Z])/g, ' $1').replace(/^./, function(str){ return str.toUpperCase(); }));</script>                           
<xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Works perfectly fine for me when testing in Firefox and Chrome, but it is a horrible code.

Comment: Aside from the general inadvisability of using document.write, what you have would work fine - is there more code? Does the debugger highlight that line?

Comment: Works fine [TEST](http://jsfiddle.net/ZtU6h/) and @adeneo yes it is a horrible code

Comment: yeah it is workig fine.... actually i am using this code in XSLT for xml.... let me update my question